# Short read on named pipes (matlab->linux)

Tags: c, linux, matlab, named-pipes

I've got some code I'm writing that is expecting messages from a Matlab program via a named pipe, e.g., "/tmp/named_pipe_0".  I can get pipes mkfifo and opened find, but when the C program goes to read() from the pipe, instead of the expected 5004 bytes, I'll get short values like 4096, 904, 5000, 4096, etc.   I've already verified that Matlab is supposedly sending the correct 5004 bytes (at least, it's told to), so I'm wondering what the cause is.  Anyone run across something like this before?

Matt

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, a read on a pipe/socket/named pipe gives you back the data as soon as something is available.

If you need to read 5004 byte, you'd do it in a loop that appends you your own buffer up till you get that many bytes (or an error or eof occurs)

e.g.

```
size_t readn(int fd, void *buf, ssize_t len)
{
    ssize_t tot = 0;
    unsigned char *p = buf;

    while (tot != len) {
       ssize_t r = read(fd, p + tot, len - tot);
       if (r == 0) //premature end of reading
           break;
       else if (r == -1) //error
          return -1
       tot += r;
    }

   return tot;
}

...
char buf[5004];
if (readn(pipe_fd, buf, sizeof buf) != sizeof buf) {
   // something went bad
} else {
   //got all the 5004 bytes
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nos, I'll give that a try.

@WilliamPursell - I thought fread() was for *FILE, not int file descriptors, or is there some subtle variant I'm not aware of?

Comment: `fread` is indeed for a FILE *.  Instead of trying to implement the functionality of `fread` using `read`, it's much simpler to get a FILE * with `fdopen`.